# AngularJS and Font Awesome Issue

Tags: angularjs, font-awesome

### View

```
<li ng-repeat="avatar in avatars" style="background-image: url(images/{{avatar.bg}})">
  <i>{{avatar.icon}}</i>      
</li>
<li><i>&#xf09b;</i></li>
```

### Controller

```
.controller('AboutCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.avatars = [
    {"icon": "&#xf09b;", "bg": "github.jpeg", "href": "http://google.com"},
    {"icon": "&#xf0d4;", "bg": "twitter.jpeg", "href": "http://google.com"},
    {"icon": "&#xf081;", "bg": "gplus.jpg", "href": "http://google.com"},
    {"icon": "&#xf082;", "bg": "fb.jpg", "href": "http://google.com"}
  ];
})
```

### Issue

I used @font-face to add 'Font Awesome' to my CSS file and then set it as the font for all `<i>` elements. But for some reason my fonts won't render when I use Angular to insert the special character values into an `<i>` element via "avatar.icon".

I added the second `<li>` group in the view to make sure it was indeed Angular and not a CSS specificity problem, but the special character in the second `<i>` tag renders just fine.

I know there is something I'm overlooking, but I cannot figure it out. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: FYI, I haven't tested it with this case (so I'm not posting as an answer) but I had a similar issue with another HTML entity character and I solved it by using a JS literal character instead.  ie. instead of writing `&#xf09b;`, try using `\uf09b`.  You shouldn't need to use `ng-bind-html` any more, just a regular binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to include the `ngSanitize` module and use `ng-bind-html` like this:

```
<i ng-bind-html='avatar.icon'></i>
```

Documentation:  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive:ngBindHtml

Note that there is a separate library, angular-sanitize.js and you'd include the module like this:

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ngCookies','ngResource','ngSanitize'])
```

Update:

Per one of the comments, you can also use:   `ng-bind-html-unsafe="{expression}"`  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe

Comment: Thanks for the help. Only correction is <i ng-bind-html='{{avatar.icon}}'></i> should be <i ng-bind-html='avatar.icon'></i> drop the double brackets when dealing with Angular specific attributes.

Comment: You are right, I just typed it out too quickly.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: I think this has been updated so you can do it without the ngSanitize library, just use ng-bind-html-unsafe (the change being -unsafe appended).

Worked fine for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

### index.html

```
<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

- !important make sure you add angular-sanitize.js or none of this will
  work.

### app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/home'
      })
  });
```

- inject 'ngSantize' into myApp

### main.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('AboutCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.avatars = [
      {"icon": "&#xf09b;", "bg": "twitter.jpeg", "href": "http://google.com"},
      {"icon": "&#xf0d4;", "bg": "twitter.jpeg", "href": "http://google.com"},
      {"icon": "&#xf081;", "bg": "gplus.jpg", "href": "http://google.com"},
      {"icon": "&#xf082;", "bg": "fb.jpg", "href": "http://google.com"}
    ];
  });
```

- nothing strange here just setting the scope

### about.html

```
<li ng-repeat="avatar in avatars" style="background-image: url(images/{{avatar.bg}})">
  <a class="social" href="{{avatar.href}}" target="_blank">
    <i ng-sanitize ng-bind-html="avatar.icon"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

- using ng-bind-html to handle the special characters correctly
- make sure you do not add curly braces inside ng-bind-html

### Explanation

Above is my full solution with some surrounding code for bearing.